# Replace id number with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I have an id like this:
`s2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_41_commodity_id`

Now, I want to replace the number after the phrase `guidances_` with itself + 1. In this case, I want `s2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_41_commodity_id` -> `s2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_42_commodity_id`

I tried `(s2\w*_)(\d+)(\w*_id)` at regex101.com, and I am getting stuck here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ?? your regex works. and the replacement has to be done in your program. Regex cant add/count

Comment: The number you're looking for is in group 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use any group and only match the correct id :

```
\d+(?=_[A-Za-z]+_id$)
```

Here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/HEqIn2/5). It uses a positive lookahead, in order to only find the number which is right before `_someword_id`.

It makes it easier to replace :

```js
var str = "s2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_41_commodity_id";
var new_str = str.replace(/\d+(?=_[A-Za-z]+_id$)/, function($0) {
  return Number($0)+1;
});
console.log(new_str);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the regex you sent me will try to replace the part guidances_ also, and this is not my goal. I just wanna replace the number after it. Could you please double check it?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works flawlessly now. Have a wonderful day. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the regex you are already using works, the only necessary part of the code is the callback method:

```js
var s = "s2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_41_commodity_id";
var res = s.replace(/(s2\w*_)(\d+)(\w*_id)/, function($0,$1,$2,$3) {
  return $1+(Number($2)+1)+$3;
});
console.log(res);
```

The number you want to increment is in Group 2, so `$2` is cast to number and incremented.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Nevertheless, when I tried your solution and 
@RomanPerekhrest I got this instead s2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_411_commodity_id

Comment: That's weird. Both examples should work. Did you forget to convert to a number with `Number($2)`?

Comment: @ĐỗTiến: Which browser are you using? Try `parseInt($2, 10) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach with `String.replace` function:

```js
var id_value = 's2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_41_commodity_id',
    replaced = id_value.replace(/(guidances_)(\d+)(?=_)/g, function ($m0, $m1, $m2) {
        return $m1 + (parseInt($m2) + 1);
    });

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but please see my above comment.

Comment: it works according to your initial requirement  *I want s2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_41_commodity_id -> s2id_past_example_lashing_guidances_42_commodity_id*